# How can I open org-journal-new-entry in full window?

Tags: org-mode, org-journal

I am using [org-journal-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgJournal). When I apply `org-journal-new-entry (M-j)`, in order to open today’s journal file and start a new entry, it opens the entry in splitted half window. Example view:

[image]

Instead can the new-entry open in full window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h v org-journal-find-file` says:

```
org-journal-find-file is a variable defined in ‘org-journal.el’.

Its value is ‘find-file-other-window’

The function to use when opening an entry.

Set this to ‘find-file’ if you don’t want org-journal to split your window.

  You can customize this variable.
```

So customize the variable and set it to `find-file`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will work in your special case, but I have in my initialization file entries like this below which prevent buffers to open in a sub-window. It is useful if the created buffer names follow a pattern which makes it possible to identify them:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '(re-matching-buf-name display-buffer-same-window))
```

See the available help ( for example: C-h o -> display-buffer-alist ) for more details how it works.

I am using this for following kinds of buffers:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("*Help*"        display-buffer-same-window)) ;; C-h
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("*Apropos*"     display-buffer-same-window)) ;; C-h a
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("*Buffer List*" display-buffer-same-window)) ;; C-x C-b
```